# Добавление экземпляра виджета

Tags: android

Начал изучать Java для Android и для практики решил создать виджет.

Предполагалось, что он будет работать на Android 4.2.2.

Все делал, как написано в умных книжках и, вроде бы, все работает, но столкнулся с такой **проблемой**:

виджет имеет Config Activity. Данные сохраняются в `Preferences`. При добавлении виджета открывается `Activity` с настройками. К этому моменту уже срабатывают методы `onEnabled` (если это первый экземпляр) и `onUpdate`. Если, при этом, нажать кнопку "Назад", то на устройстве с API 21 и выше, вызываются методы `onDeleted` и `onDisabled` (если это последний экземпляр).

Но, на устройстве с API 17, при нажатии кнопки "Назад" - виджет не добавляется, но и метод `onDeleted` не вызывается. Система где-то (очень бы хотелось понять где вообще сохраняются `id` добавляемых экземпляров виджета?) сохраняет `id` экземпляра виджета и считает, что он добавлен.

Т.е. если потом добавить виджет и его удалить, то метод `onDeleted` при удалении сработает, а метод `onDisabled` - нет, т.к. система будет считать, что это не последний экземпляр.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему?

Ниже примерный код:

```
public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override
public void onEnabled (Context context) {
    //Метод вызывается при добавлении первого экземпляра виджета
    super.onEnabled(context);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate (Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    //Метод вызывается при обновлении виджета
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    SharedPreferences mConfig = context.getSharedPreferences(ConfigActivity.APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    for (int id : appWidgetIds) {
        updateWidget(context, appWidgetManager, mConfig, id);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDeleted (Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    //Метод вызывается при удалении каждого экземпляра виджета
    super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
}

@Override
public void onDisabled (Context context) {
    //Метод вызывается при удалении последнего экземпляра виджета
    super.onDisabled(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = (context.getSharedPreferences(ConfigActivity.APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)).edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.apply();
}
```

Метод `updateWidget` опущен за ненадобностью.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
        widgetID = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }

    if (widgetID == AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
        finish();
    }

    resultValue = new Intent();
    resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetID);
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, resultValue);

    setContentView(R.layout.num_widget_config);

    mConfig = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

}
```

Далее метод `onClick` с сохранением настроек, возвратом `RESULT_OK` и зарытием `Activity`.